# What is a good strategy for guaranteeing resource reloads (via ajax) during development?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I've consistently not been able to find a way to reload data to the browser.

For example in FF 10 - Hitting Control-Shift-R is suppose to do this.  Sometimes it does, some times it does not.

I've read that if you change the URL of the requested resource the browser will re-load the data as new.  I believe this.  I'm going to implement it.

What I'm going to do is simply us PHP to change the file name by appending a unix time-stamp to it.  This will be done on each resource request.

I'm planning on writing a PHP maintenance script ( say updateResource.php ) that renames the resource and at the same time writes PHP code that sets the name into the PHP script.

so for my .js resource

```
file1.js
```

becomes

```
file1_timestamp.js
```

and

the contents of php file go from

```
$file_name = file1.js

$file_name = file1_timestamp.js
```

PHP later writes to .htm file which javascript then knows to pull from the DOM and load the file dynamically via Ajax Call.

And this time it is not cached b.c. the URL changed.

Is this a good way to guarantee reloads?

Comment: it's usualy done like `script.js?_ts=[timestamp]` for scripts, you NEED to reload each request

Comment: why do you have a question mark there?....sorry this is an ajax call

Comment: It's called a query string, it's simply a parameter sent with the GET request. If you don't use it on the php side, it's simply ignored. As a side effect, changing the parameter till invalidate the client side cache

Comment: @HiroProtagonist You can pass URL query parameters to script URLs in `<script></script>` tags just like you can with URLs in address bars.  Using it on URLs to scripts in your HTML is an easy way to tell the browser to load the newest version of the script from the server and not the cache.

Comment: Whats wrong with expiry headers?

Comment: Js files can have expiry headers?

Comment: ....WAIT...so I don't have to change the actual file name??

Comment: @HiroProtagonist you don't :)

Comment: nope you don't have to change the file name just add a diff number to the request

Comment: and I can do that via Ajax calls as well I take it?

Comment: @all...Rasmus answered below...Thanks...saved me from going down a wrong long path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To force client side reload, `script.ts?v.xx` works well and is widely used. Replace xx with the current release of your application at compile time. This way you wont have to rename the file.

Comment: timestamp is the version in my case.....what is the question mark for...I did not mention but this is an ajax call.

Comment: See my comment on the other answer about the question mark.. About the timestamp i read the question a bit wrong. You can set the timestamp in javascript to force a reload.

Comment: Nice...way easier...then what I was about todo...I can do this via ajax as well?

Comment: Yes, a it's still simple HTTP requests. You can send whatever you want as parameters with it. You should have seen and should use this technique for a wide variety of things as a web developer. A common use case could be "product.html?id=5" to display a certain product on a page dynamically, reading the id 5 on server side.

Comment: I have always separated the two until now.

Comment: *Or*... you could just learn how HTTP works (it's not exactly complicated) paying special attention to how client-side caching can be controlled, configure your web server properly and the problem disappears *without having to introduce unnecessary code that is there just for development purposes*. Most web servers provide a mechanism to carpet-bomb the problem by adding an `Expires:` header with a date in the past and a `Cache-Control: no-cache` header to every response - in Apache you can do this in a .htaccess and just not bring the file across to the live server.

Comment: @Dave...I know how HTTP works...but like I said...I've never had this need before...and I always prefer code over configuration if that makes sense...a lot of web development is preference.